# Проблема с VLAN-ом

Tags: сеть, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

Решал такую л/р: есть 3 отдела, в каждом по 2 компьютера. Надо каждый отдел объединить в отдельный VLAN. С этим я спрвился. Задание дальше: во второй отдел временно добавили 1 компьютер, который должен быть в 1 отделе. Нужно объединить его с Vlan-ом 1-ого отдела. Делал как и всё остальное-не работает. Я должен этот компьютер пинговать с одного из компьютеров в 1 отделе, но не получается
[image: cкрин]

Comment: [ссылка]https://drive.google.com/open?id=17touSLdU71yIqwTfXVqy8U0GVIZY0KJK

Comment: Как настроены свичи? какие вланы на каких портах,  где тегованные, к каким портам какие станции подключены?

Comment: Switch0: fa0/1 и fa0/2 - access, fa0/3-trunk; vlan 2; Switch1: fa0/1 fa0/2 - vlan 3, а fa0/3 access vlan 2, fa0/4 trunk; анологично и 3

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку:

```
SW0: 
Порт 1 VLAN 101 untagged => PC0
Порт 2 VLAN 101 untagged => PC1
Порт 3 VLAN 101-103 tagged => SW5 Порт 1

SW4: 
Порт 1 VLAN 102 untagged => PC7
Порт 2 VLAN 102 untagged => PC8
Порт 3 VLAN 101 untagged => PC9
Порт 4 VLAN 101-103 tagged => SW5 Порт 2

SW2: 
Порт 1 VLAN 103 untagged => PC4
Порт 2 VLAN 103 untagged => PC5
Порт 3 VLAN 101-103 tagged => SW5 Порт 3

SW5: 
Порт 1 VLAN 101-103 tagged => SW0 Порт 3
Порт 2 VLAN 101-103 tagged => SW4 Порт 4
Порт 3 VLAN 101-103 tagged => SW2 Порт 3
```

untagged == access

tagged == trunk